# REGEXP Non Capturing Group is Capturing with TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

I have data, see below, that I want to parse using REGEXP in my TCL script:

```
Mar 31 11:30:00 UTC+0100 2015
Mar 31 17:00:00 UTC+0100 2015
Mar 31 17:30:00 UTC+0100 2015
Apr 1 11:30:00 UTC+0100 2015
Apr 1 17:00:00 UTC+0100 2015
Apr 1 17:30:00 UTC+0100 2015
Apr 2 11:30:00 UTC+0100 2015
```

I want to just pull out the day of the month from the data above.
This is the regular expression I have come up with so far and I don't know why it's not working.

```
(?:\w{3}\s)(\d{1,2})(?:\s)
```

I have tested it on the RegExr site with my sample data and it appears to work correctly there; it returns the day of the month in the group but when I run it in my TCL script it returns all of the match, i.e. the non capturing groups are being returned.

Is there something I'm missing here? I'm not great with regular expressions.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Below is the code sample from my script. I have a CSV file that I am reading from where sData6 column contains the date/time information above.

```
while {[gets $fInputFile line] >= 0} {
    set aAllOptions [split $line ,]
    lassign $aAllOptions sData1 sData2 sData3 sData4 sData5 sData6

    regexp -all {(?:\w{3}\s)(\d{1,2})(?:\s)} $sData6 regexData6

    puts "Printing regexp value $regexData6\n"
```

My puts statement is returning:

```
Mar 31
```

I want it for just return:

```
31
```

Comment: Could you please put the code you are using? Maybe put a sample code to reproduce the issue you are having?

Comment: @Jerry I have updated my question with a sample of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Ok, it's just a matter of syntax. I'll put an answer in a few

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex you are using works fine, it is just a matter of syntax like I said in the comments:

```
regexp -all {(?:\w{3}\s)(\d{1,2})(?:\s)} $sData6 -> regexData6 
puts "Printing regexp value $regexData6\n"
```

The syntax is:

```
regexp ?switches? exp string ?matchVar? ?subMatchVar subMatchVar ...?
```

[manpage](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm#M3)

What you were using is `matchVar`, which contains the full match. `subMatchVar` contains the first captured group, and the one you needed.

I'm saving the `matchVar` in `->` (practically any variable name could be used here and since I won't need it, I don't need something meaningful).

---

FWIW, you can use this shorter regex to achieve the same result:

```
regexp -all {\w{3}\s(\d{1,2})\s} $sData6 -> regexData6
```

Comment: That did the trick and script is working correctly now. I'm unable to vote your answer up as I am a new user.

Comment: @p_cos Don't worry about voting up answers to questions you asked; the upvote mechanism is mostly for _other_ people to use. (Right now, it's got two upvotes, so it's working fine…)